# What other languages can make arrays via pointer manipulation?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, traversal

We've written the following recursive function in my C++ class.

```
bool contains(int arr[], int n, int val){
  if(n == 0) return false;          // Escape clause
  if(arr[0] == val) return true;  // Second escape clause
  return contains(arr+1, n-1, val);
}
```

My professor said that C/C++/Assembler are the only mainstream languages which support this kind of array traversal. What other languages allow for this kind of search by changing the pointer address?

Comment: Pascal, maybe. Pointer arithmetic is not safe, and generally not worth it (from recent languages that have pointers, Go disallowed arithmetic explicitly).

Comment: @Dani: Yeah, misread the code slightly, sorry.

Comment: Just curious, what happens if arr[n] contains the value of interest on the initial call to this method, where n > 0? Won't you return false in that case?

Comment: @dcp `n` is the length of the array so `arr[n]` is out of bounds. Also, is assembly considered a mainstream language?

Comment: @dcp: If `n` is size, `arr[n]` is outside of the array.

Comment: @dcp: the search is exclusive

Comment: Yes, but now he's edited the code so it's different.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: The Pascal standard does not allow pointer arithmetic, but many implementations do.

Comment: @MichaelBurr - Correct, I used the wrong example. Corrected.

Comment: In `C#`, when you are using the instruction `unsafe` you can manipulate pointers on arrays.

Comment: This isn't even c++, in c++ you use `std::vector`. this is C, and this type of manipulation is only needed in historic languages.

Comment: @Dani this is definitely valid and correct C++; if you doubt it, try compiling it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It's not idiomatic C++.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus that doesn't make it not C++. Also I like this new automatically updating comment system.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I didn't say it doesn't compile in C++, I just say its not the C++ way of doing it.

Comment: It's still technically valid C++. Academic C++ is still C++.

Comment: @Dani Make `arr` a `std::vector<int>::iterator` and the algorithm works unmodified the same (though it could be made more idiomatic by using `end()` rather than the length, and omitting the recursion for that matter). You've got a point, but for this particular function, there's little difference.

Comment: @delnan: iterator might be similar to raw pointer in C++, but in other languages you can make an iterator but not raw pointer so there is a big difference.

Comment: @Dani Pointers are certainly rarer and more powerful, but I'm talking about this specific example. If all you need is representing a point in a sequence with means of moving that point and getting the value at that point, you don't need pointers.

Comment: There's D, Fortran, unsafe C#, and some flavours of BASIC and Pascal. I don't know if you'd call any of them "mainstream" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All languages which support numeric indexes on arrays would work for this general algorithm.  It has nothing to do with pointer manipulation.

Pointer manipulation is usually taken advantage of for string based algorithms in C.  For example it's possible to implement `strlen` as follows.

```
size_t strlen(char* pValue) {
  char* pStart = pValue;
  while (*pValue != '\0') {
    pValue++;
  }
  return pValue - pStart;
}
```

This code would work equally well on a `char[]` or `char*` input. This type of manipulation of pointer is indeed limited to languages which both expose pointers and expose arrays in that way.

This isn't limited to C / C++ / Assembler though. It could also be done in say C#